# setLatestEventInfo(...) is undefined for the type Notification

Tags: android

I kwnow that "setLatestEventInfo" is deprecated. But I must use it for compatibility with api lv 8 devices, because new notification call function is not compatible with api 8 devices.

I use "setLatestEventInfo" in some proyects and I get a deprecated warning, but in this new proyect I get "is undefined for the type Notification"

```
Notification note = new   Notification(R.drawable.abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha,
                "", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent;


            intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

> note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "", "", pi);

```
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        ((Service) context).startForeground(1337, note);
```

If I use Notification.Builder:

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new
>   android.app.Notification.Builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved in project properties changing from Android api 6.0 to 5.1.1.

Comment: I need to target api 6. What's the right way to fix it for 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to implement Notification as this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.notitfications.MYNOTIFICATION");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker("Ticker text");
        builder.setContentTitle("Content of Notification");               
        builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
        builder.setNumber(100);
        builder.build();

        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager.notify(11, myNotication);
```

Comment: Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.Notification.Builder

Comment: you need to change min SdkVersion in this line on Manifest to 11: android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: No, I need to run my app in api lv 8 devices. I post answer.

Comment: why you vote down me? you don't worthy receive helping

Comment: I vote down you because you don´t read my question: "I must use it for compatibility with api lv 8 devices, because new notification call function is NOT COMPATIBLE with api 8 devices" so you answer with redundant info that is in my question.